# how can I interpect all requests between docker containers?

Tags: docker, mitmproxy

I am looking for a way to intercept all the HTTP requests between docker containers, for debugging purposes.

I am using [MitmProxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) and I can intercept the requests done from the containers to the internet (configured the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables), but not the ones done internally to other containers in the network (Using their DNS name).

Is there any way I can achieve that with MitmProxy or any other tool?

My idea is that if I have a Microservices application running locally, having a way to see all the requests between applications without needing to modify application code, would be a great way to debug communication issues between the services.

Comment: What is your operating system? Are you doing both http and https?

Comment: Linux (Fedora 33). Was testing with http. would want to have it working with https eventually,

Comment: I found this article, (https://byteplumbing.net/2018/01/inspecting-docker-container-network-traffic/). Maybe I have to run Mitmproxy and transparent mode. Would like to avoid messing too much with Network configurations for just casual debugging sessions if there is another way.

Comment: I was about to ask if you can try to bind mitmproxy to the docker0 interface, and asked for the OS to know if you have the docker0 interface.

Answer (score 3):

You can intercept calls between containers using [PnTest](https://pntest.io/) which uses mitmproxy under-the-hood but automatically re-configures your containers to route all outbound traffic through a proxy.